Clean up "Coinbase transaction" duplicates
I came across a recent question that was esentially "what is the coinbase transaction?"  I figured a duplicate question existed so I went searching. I found far more than just a few that could be a duplicate. Instead of submitting a close vote for all of them I think a moderator should do the corrections. Most or all of these should be marked as a duplicate of a canonical version of "what is the Coinbase transaction and what does it do?" There's a few in there that can serve well as that canonical question. 

How does the bitcoin transaction fee get paid to miner(s)?
Where do the mined bitcoins go?
How does bitcoin reward who find the block?
Who issues the transaction of reward when a miner solves the block?
Is the reward for successfully mining a block a transaction on the bitcoin network?
How exactly do new bitcoins come into existence?
When creating a block, who actually generates the 25 bitcoins that act as a reward?
Transaction marked as "Newly generated coins" on Blockchain.info
How are bitcoins generated during mining?
How do miners receive transaction fees?
How does a miner collects the fees?
How does the network apply credit for created blocks?

These are just the questions tagged coinbase-transaction. There are probably more.
While you're there, several of the questions tagged coinbase-transaction are actually about coinbase.com transactions.  This misuse might be prevented if the coinbase.com tag was changed to coinbase-company. Or maybe the coinbase-transaction tag except needs to state clearly "do not use for questions about coinbase.com". 

This could be a very nice cleanup. But IMO "how do the miners collect fees" should remain as a separate question to "how does bitcoin reward who finds the block", because to new users the block reward and transaction fees may seem quite unrelated and thus a weird thing to close as duplicate. The former type of question can include more information on how the transaction fees from each transaction are calculated per-block and validated, while the latter could include info on what data the coinbase transaction includes.
Edit: it appears What is the coinbase? may be a suitable question to link to
And please feel free to suggest edits to the questions which have the incorrect tags!

I see your point. There should probably be a divide there.
